# What free CRMs are available for my website?

Tags: crm

Searched hard but all I found was a page listing "commercial open source" CRMs, i.e. what you have to pay for.

On the lookout for free CRMs so I don't have to build one!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got a list of 10 free CRMs!

[The Top 10 Open-Source CRM Solutions](http://www.insidecrm.com/features/top-open-source-solutions-121307/)

1. [SugarCRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com/)
2. [SplendidCRM](http://www.splendidcrm.com/)
3. [CentricCRM](http://www.centriccrm.com/)
4. [Hipergate](http://www.hipergate.org/)
5. [Compiere](http://www.compiere.com/)
6. [Vtiger CRM](http://www.vtiger.com)
7. [CentraView](http://www.centraview.com/)
8. [XRMS CRM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xrms/)
9. [Cream CRM](http://www.linuxsoft.cz/en/sw_detail.php?id_item=4440)
10. [Tustena CRM](http://www.tustena.com/crm/)

Also got multi-purpose suites.

[Compiere](http://www.compiere.com/products/capabilities/index.php) or [Dolibarr](http://www.dolibarr.org/features)

- ERP - Enterprise Resource Planning
- CRM - Customer Relationship Management

[XRMS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xrms/)

- CRM - Customer Relationship Management
- SFA -  Sales Force Automation suite
- BI - Business Intelligence tools
- CTI - Computer Telephony Integration

[Vtiger CRM](http://www.vtiger.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=55)

- CRM - Customer Relationship Management
- SFA - Sales Force Automation
- IM - Inventory Management

Comment: www.saleslifecycle.com < free for single users

Answer (score 4):

I was looking the same in these days. Looks like [SugarCRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com/) being a great choice.
I played a lot yesterday with SugarCRM, Zoho CRM and Salesforce. Only SugarCRM, in its community edition, is open source and free. Zoho is nice (and free up to 3 users). Saleforce is more expensive.

Edit. I checked out vTiger crm, and it looks event better than SugarCRM, and there are also some plugins for integration in Outlook, Thunderbird and iPhone. I think I will try to install it ASAP.

Comment: vTiger CRM has been designed on Sugar CRM as far as i know but its interface does look very pretty and feels better than Sugar CRM do elaborate on it when u do try it out Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am developing some modules for Vtiger CRM tring to extend some existing modules(for ex: contacs,mail,calendar). My opinion is that Vtiger Crm covers 80% of the standar requirement. There are some limitation in extending the system. Hardcoded query and lots of magic numbers. (ex: if (a==5) else b(a==6) and so on). A new version 5.1 is coming out (is in rc1).

Answer (score 1):

At an old job of mine we set up [Sugar CRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/) for the sales guys, and it worked wonderfully.  You should definitely check it out.